# Notification bar disappears on update

Tags: android, notifications

```
public void createNotification(
    String title, String fileName,
    boolean setProgressBar,
    int maxValue, int progress, int notificationId,
    boolean firstTime) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    if (firstTime) {
        builder.setContentText(fileName);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    }
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    if (setProgressBar) {
        builder.setProgress(maxValue, progress, false);
    }
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
       (NotificationManager)
         context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
}
```

I am creating notification from some other activity and updating from some other activity.  I update with this:

```
notificationManager.createNotification(
    "Downloading", document.getName(),
    true,
    (int) document.getContentLength(), (int)completedBytes,
    (int) document.getContentLength(),
    false);
```

I am very new to this. Any lead will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Corrected code formatting; minor word-smithing

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to completely rebuild the notification every time you update it, so you should remove the check for `firstTime` in your `createNotification()` method.

**Edit:** For those interested in a more detailed explanation, the updated notification isn't showing because every notification requires a content title and text, as well as a small icon, as indicated in the Android Developers [notifications](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#builder%20Notifcations) page. Since the updated notification does *not* contain those (`firstTime` is false) the resulting notification will be invalid. Calling `notify()` on the `NotificationManager` with the same id will still replace the notification, but since that one is invalid it won't show a new one.

**Edit (16/06/21):** The following class can be used to create and update progress notifications and is based on the file you uploaded. To update a notification just call `createNotification(...)` again and the system will take care of properly changing the notification.

```
public class SDCNotificationManager {
    public final static String OPEN_NOTIFICATION = "notification_open";
    public final static int MAX_PROGRESS_VALUE = 100;

    /*
     * Creates or updates a progress notification
     */
    public static void createNotification(Context context, String title, String fileName, int currentProgress, int maxProgress, int notificationId) {

        boolean notificationEnabled = SettingsManager.getInstance().(SettingsKey.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION);
        if (notificationEnabled) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setAction(OPEN_NOTIFICATION);
            // build notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setContentText(fileName);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setProgress(maxProgress, currentProgress, false);
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            // send notification to system service
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Everytime I was creating a new Notification.Builder, due to that I was not able to update the same notification.
So I made the builder static and it worked. Don't know why.
Can you explain this ?

Comment: Could you post your updated code, please, so I can take a closer look at it. Also note that in order to properly update the notification you have to use the same notification id, so `document.getContentLength()` might not be the best option.

Comment: I am not able to upload my code, it says formatting error

Comment: https://mdocs.sap.com/mcm/public/v1/open?shr=9mkgE--yP6_a5-Iipw3n40DNGFcQq7hK17lwxTkMhNo&obj=ew5QaYcwsfIQjTQLtcpoLIK3S8JTAWg6u_sIS5QQeXE

I have uploaded the file here, open the link

Comment: Sorry for the late response, your code works because `static` variables are only only created once per class. Thus your progress update method has access to the `Notification.Builder` created in the `createNotification` method. However this is not the best way to do it. I have updated my answer with some code that should also work and avoids `static` variables.